# Can’t boot Ubuntu after failing to use Arch Linux

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 202.04 LTS installed on my HP laptop. I tried switching to Arch Linux after a while with https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_from_existing_Linux and gave up after https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide#Install_essential_packages step. When I tried to boot my laptop later on, it took forever to load and took me to a console like screen and outputs

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 371371/31227904 files, 7055823/124895488 blocks
…
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

I do not know what to do in this situation. I pressed Ctrl-D and it still took forever to load. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There's a chance that something where those `...` characters are has critical information for us about *why* you are in emergency mode.  If you did a partial install of Arch Linux and it overwrote Ubuntu at one point during the setup or install step then that may explain why you're on emergency mode - you have a broken system and you may have to reinstall Ubuntu clean.

Comment: `After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance` Have you tried to press Enter and run `journalctl -xb` ?

Comment: @mestia I just got this too, I had to remove the offending disk from fstab when in recovery mode. Anything that looked at it would hang.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really know how to fix it, so I simply just reinstalled Ubuntu. Luckily I haven't installed much on it and I can easily recover. Sorry for not putting the errors where the `...` was, I could only use my iPad and didn't bother typing up 6 long lines of errors.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer.